# Import Map created in OCAD in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, ocad

I have a map created with the OCAD Map Builder (https://www.ocad.com/en/). I would like to import this map in ArcGIS Pro so that I can create a version of the map that is compatible with the ArcGIS Runtime for mobile Devices.

OCAD offers multiple export options including exporting to Shapefiles or DXF. Unfortunately the color and symbology information is lost when exporting in either a Shapefile or DXF.

Is it possible to somehow transfer the Symbology and color Information from the OCAD File to ArcGIS Pro?

I found the OpenOrienteering Mapper (https://github.com/OpenOrienteering/mapper) which can read OCADs .ocd files. But unfortunately it does not offer a way to export the map to any other compatible Format.

Any ideas how I could transfer as much information as possible from the OCAD file into ArcGIS Pro??